# Create Binary Tree from Ancestor Matrix

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

The question is how to create a binary tree, given its ancestor matrix. I found a cool solution at http://www.ritambhara.in/build-binary-tree-from-ancestor-matrics/. Problem is that it involves deleting rows and columns from the matrix. Now how do I do that? Can anybody suggest a pseudocode for this? Or, is there any better algo possible?

Comment: the blog in question belongs to me.. Sorry for the delay, but I have added the code to the blog post (in question) http://www.ritambhara.in/build-binary-tree-from-ancestor-matrics/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to actually delete the rows and columns. You can either flag them as deleted in some additional array, or you can make them all zeros, which I think will be effectively the same (actually, you'll still need to know that they are removed, so you don't choose them again in step 4.c - so, flagging the node as deleted should be good enough).

Here are the modifications to the pseudocode from the page:

4.b.

```
used[temp] = true;
for (i = 0 to N) 
    Sum[i] -= matrix[i][temp]; (aka decrement sum if temp is a predecessor of i)
    matrix[i][temp] = 0;
```

4.c. Look for all rows for which Sum[i] == 0 and used[i] == false.

Comment: I kind of though that, but am having difficulty in implementing it. Can you provide a pseudo-code?

Answer (score 2):

This reminds me of the [**Dancing Links**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Links) used by Doanld Knuth to implement his [**Algorithm X**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm_X)

It's basically a structure of circular doubly linked list.  <strike>You could maintain a seperate *Sum* array and update it with removal of rows and columns as required.</strike>

Actually you don't need to maintain a separate *Sum* array.
**Edit:**

I meant - 
You could use a structure made up of circular 2D linked lists.
The node structure would somewhat look like:

```
struct node{
        int val;
        struct node *left;
        struct node *right;
        struct node *down;
};
```

The Top-most and Left-most List is the header List for the vertices(Binary tree node values).

If vertex `j` is an ancestor of vertex `i`, build a (empty)new node such that `j` column's current `down` is assigned this new node and `i's` current `left` is assigned this new node.
 Note: Structure can be easily built by scanning each rows of ancestor matrix from left to right and inserting rows from 0 to N. (assuming `N` is the no. of vertices here)

[image: Image1]

[image: Image4]

I borrowed these images from [Image1](http://sudokugarden.de/de/loesen/dancing-links) and [Image2](http://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~jchu/publicportal/sudoku/sudoku.paper.html) to give an idea of the grid. 2nd image is missing the Left-most header though.

If `N` is no. of vertices. There can be at worse `O(N^2)` entries in ancestor matrix(in case tree is skewed) or on average `O(NlogN)` entries.
**To search for current Root: `O(N)`** 
Assuming a dummy node to start with, linearly scan the Leftmost header and choose a node with `node->down->right == node->down`.

**To delete this vertex information: `O(N)`** 
**Deleting row:`O(1)`**

```
node->down = node->down->down;
```

**Deleting column:`O(N)`** 

Goto the corresponding column - say(p):

```
node* q = p;
while(q->down != p){
    q->down->left->right = q->down->right;
    q->down->right->left = q->down->left;
    q = q->down;
}
```

After discovering current Root you can assign it to it's parent node and insert them into a Queue to process the next level as per that link suggests you to.

Overall time complexity: N + (N-1) + (N-2) +.... = `O(N^2)`. 
Worst case space complexity `O(N^2)`

Though there is no big improvement in the asymptotic run-time from the solution you already have. I thought it's worth mentioning since, this kind of structure can be particularly useful for storing sparse matrices and defining operations like multiplication on them or if you are working with some backtracking algorithm which removes a row/column and later backtracks and adds it again like Knuth's AlgorithmX.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to update the matrix. Just decrement the values in the sum array for any descendents of the current node, and check if any of them reaches zero, which means the current noe is that last ancestor, e.g. the direct parent:

```
for (i = 0 to N) 
    if matrix[i][temp]==1:
      Sum[i]=Sum[i]-1
      if Sum[i]==0:
        add i as child of temp
        add i to queue
```